# How to authorize cloud66 toolbelt

Tags: cloud66

I dont understand how to use cloud66 toolbelt. In docs stated you need to run command `cx stacks list` - it opens cloud66 site in browser with Auth Code line. What should I do next? Should I put this Auth Code somewhere? Where?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the Auth code shown in the browser, paste it back into your terminal and then hit return. If successful you will see message in the terminal saying something like "Token is cached in /home/username/.cloud66/cx.json"